# How to connect to MySQl db on linux server using toad?

Tags: mysql, toad, remote-connection

How to connect to MySQl db on linux server using toad?

what i should give on host?

i get the error

Can't connect to MySQL server on 'tinywall' (10061)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Toad for MySQL? If so, check out [this installation guide](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/mysql-databas/toad-for-mysql-freeware/) if you missed anything, or this [PDF guide from ToadSoft](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadmysql/Toad_InstallGuide.pdf).

Also, have a look at this quote from [MySQL's page on connection problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html):

> The error (2003) Can't connect to
>   MySQL server on 'server' (10061) 
>   indicates that the network connection
>   has been refused. You should check
>   that there is a MySQL server running,
>   that it has network connections
>   enabled, and that the network port you
>   specified is the one configured on the
>   server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you /etc/mysql/my.conf

- Is "skip-networking" active?
- Is "bind-address" set to 127.0.0.1?