# Toad not connecting to mysql remote server

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, ssh, toad

I am using Toad on my windows machine to connect to mysql on the remote ubuntu linux server. And it is not connecting it. It says "Can't connect to SSH server on '': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it  22." I guess 22 is the ssh port and I provided the default mysql db server port i.e. 3306. I don't know what's happening

Comment: Does that mysql server accepts remote conection. If you have access to that mysql server ... can you check the `ini` file and make sure remote connection is allowed?

Comment: yes, that server accepts remote connections. I actually used ssh to connect to that server and installed LAMP architecture from the same remote windows machine on which the toad is installed. So that's not a problem.

Comment: Take a look @ this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344331/how-to-connect-to-mysql-db-on-linux-server-using-toad

Comment: I had a look at that post before posting this question. Although his problem is different. And the answers there didn't helped me.

Comment: not sure exactly what's going wrong but want to take a look this another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669886/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-database-on-a-remote-linux-server-from-a-windows-gui-t

Comment: thanks for that. but its still not working

Answer (score 4):

After 20 hrs of trying, finally got the solution for this.
First added the port 3306 and ip of my db server to the firewall settings of my antivirus. Then edited the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and then added remote user in the database's user table. The link below explains a lot what I did.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

It helped me. Although the settings at my server is different from this. This might help you all.

Answer (score 0):

Set connection properties as follows:

[image]

Don't forget to check "Use MySQL libraries"

Tested on my environment:

- Ubuntu server 14:04 (@ ip 10.0.0.4)
- openssh server is installed
- Port 3306 is open (`netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`)
- MySql 5.5
- Client: Windows 7, 64 bit
- TOAD 7.7